Keyboard and Mouse stop working after login when using 6.8.0-45-generic or 6.8.0-40-generic but works in 6.5.0-45-generic
I had Ubuntu 22.10. After some updates installed, few months ago, keyboard and mouse stopped working. They both are USB. I thought, upgrading to 24.04 might fix. Tried that in recovery mode. After upgrading to 24.04, still, keyboard and mouse don't work after login. Tried Advanced boot options, selected 6.5.0-45-generic and the keyboard and mouse are working in it. Issue exists in 6.8.0-40 generic also.
How to fix this in 6.8
